# Calculating portfolio log return with short sale

Tags: python

Given historical daily open and close prices of a of instruments, and a vector of weights, each value between -1 and 1 (first value is cash value so length of weights vector is 1 more than number of instruments), how to calculate daily log return of a portfolio?

I tried:

```
if ((after_step_portfolio_value + EPS) / (before_step_portfolio_value + EPS)) > 0:
    log_rate_of_return = np.log((after_step_portfolio_value + EPS) / (before_step_portfolio_value + EPS))  
elif ((after_step_portfolio_value + EPS) / (before_step_portfolio_value + EPS)) < 0:
    log_rate_of_return = -np.log(-((after_step_portfolio_value + EPS) / (before_step_portfolio_value + EPS)))
```

But it does not work correctly with short sale.

Comment: Please use formatting to make your code more readable

Comment: Please choose better names for your variables to make your code more readable